# How to show places on an integrated Google Maps display (venues, accommodations, shops etc.)

Tags: google-maps

I am integrating a Google Maps display using the JavaScript API, but I notice that it doesn't show the little icons for well known locations, like hotels, restaurants etc. What are these icons called (*places*?), and is there an option to turn them on?

I would like to have them on the display, because I want to offer users a way to put a marker on such a location if the Google geolocator doesn't give accurate enough results.

[image: Example of places]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know there is no way to automatically put all google places in one line of code.But there is always the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/places/)